# R: predict.lm() not recognizing an object

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm, predict

```
> reg.len <- lm(chao1.ave ~ lg.std.len, b.div) # b.div is my data frame imported from a CSV file
> reg.len

Call:
lm(formula = chao1.ave ~ lg.std.len, data = b.div)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)   lg.std.len  
      282.4       -115.7  

> newx <- seq(0.6, 1.4, 0.01)
> prd.len <- predict(reg.len, newdata=data.frame(x=newx), interval="confidence", level=0.90, type="response")
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'lg.std.len' not found
```

I've tried doing the lm like this: `lm(b.div$chao1.ave ~ b.div$lg.std.len)`, but then, `predict()` gives a warnings that the newdata and variables are different lengths. So, I tried the way above, and now `predict()` gives an error saying it doesn't recognize the object.  How to fix, please?

Comment: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'lg.std.len' not found

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Predict expects newdata to have the same column names (to match the formula in reg.len). You're changing it to "x" in your newdata specification, which isn't part of the formula.

```
dat <- data.frame(y=rnorm(50),lg.std.len=sample(10:15,50,replace=TRUE))
reg.len <- lm(y ~ lg.std.len,data=dat)

newx <- seq(0.6, 1.4, 0.01)
prd.len <- predict(reg.len, newdata=data.frame(lg.std.len=newx),
                   interval="confidence", level=0.90, type="response")
```

The key part is `newdata=data.frame(lg.std.len=newx)`