# Input in a lm (linear regression) function in R

Tags: r

I am doing a lm in R using vectors

```
Y<-c(1,0,1,2,5,1,4,6,2,3,5,4,6,8,4,5,7,9,7,6)
X<-c(60,63,65,70,70,70,80,80,80,80,85,89,90,90,90,90,94,100,100,100)

rg<-lm(Y ~ X)
summary(rg)


X1<-c(61,64,69,73,76,77,82,84,87,90,95,99,100,101,102,103,104,107,110,120)
```

When I use X1 as input for predict

```
Y1 <- predict(rg,X1 )
```

I have an error:

"Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : 
  numeric 'envir' arg not of length one"

This error doesn't occur if I use a data.frame object as input...I dob't understand why I need a data.frame and a vector doesn't work

am I doing something wrong??

Thanks in advance

Comment: That is the interface to predict. You are not doing anything wrong.

Comment: You need a data frame for input because that's how `predict.lm` was written. See the help at `?predict.lm`. the second argument is `newdata`, described in the documentation as *An optional data frame in which to look for variables with which to predict. If omitted, the fitted values are used.*

Comment: If you want more esoteric reasons, it probably requires a data frame because `lm` and `predict.lm` are made to be used with multiple predictors, and a data frame is the natural way to pass in multiple columns of new data. I'm sure no one thought it would be worth the effort to code a special case for models with only one predictor.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12923541/r-predict-lm-not-recognizing-an-object)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Gregor. X1, the "newdata" should be a data.frame.
 Y1 <- predict(rg, as.data.frame(X1))